# How do I center a jquery dialog to show at the center of the current viewable area of the browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I am able to center the dialog with a default position that is the exact center of the page. However when the page height is longer that the browser window, when the dialog first opens, it scrolls the entire page back to its center.

I would like to preset the dialog to be at the center relative to the screen not the page.

I believe this is what I use to initialize it:

```
dialogDiv.dialog(
{
    title: "Edit Rating",
    width: 'auto',
    height: 'auto',
    modal: true,
    resizable: false
});
```

Comment: You probably need to assign at least a fixed width (width:600px;) and then auto margin the left and right of the dialog (margin:0 auto;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it may not need much effort.

```
$("#dialog").dialog();
```

As per this article, it defaults to the center :

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#default

I too tried this and worked

This is even better:

```
$("#myDialog").position({
my: "center",
at: "center",
of: window
});
```

Sample code: http://jqueryui.com/demos/position/

Comment: actually same problem.... window seems to refer to the whole page, not just the visible area, or am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
    $("#dialog").dialog("option", "position", "center")
```